# Use a variable to define an optional argument

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I do not know what I am doing or what the terminology is. I only know that I want to use a variable (?) to avoid repeating a value in several places. But I am unable to use the value (?) of that variable (?) to pass it to a optional (keyword?) argument in emacs lisp.

Using literal values is working:

```
(setq
 org-publish-project-alist
 '(
   ("my-notes"
    :base-directory "projects/notes"
    :base-extension "org"
    :publishing-directory "html"
    ...
    )
   ))
```

Using variables is not working:

```
(setq my-base-directory "~/projects/notes")
(setq my-publising-directory "html")

(setq
 org-publish-project-alist
 '(
   ("my-notes"
    :base-directory my-base-directory
    :base-extension "org"
    :publishing-directory my-publishing-directory
    ...
    )
   ))
```

I get an error:

```
byte-code: Wrong type argument: stringp, my-base-directory
```

This is also not working:

```
(let (
      (my-base-directory "~/projects/notes")
      (my-publising-directory "html")
      )
  (setq
   org-publish-project-alist
   '(
     ("my-notes"
      :base-directory my-base-directory
      :base-extension "org"
      :publishing-directory my-publishing-directory
      ...
      )
     )))
```

I wonder why it is so difficult to access variables in emacs? Those variables are defined (I can print them), but they can not be accessed for optional arguments (are those things with a colon in front called optional or keyword arguments?)

I have tried a myriad other variations, including `(quote ...)` and using the quote symbol `'`:

```
(setq
 org-publish-project-alist
 '(
   ("my-notes"
    :base-directory 'my-base-directory
    :base-extension "org"
    :publishing-directory 'my-publishing-directory
    ...
    )
   ))
```

In this case I am getting:

```
byte-code: Wrong type argument: stringp, (quote my-base-directory)
```

I just need to use the variable to set the optional argument. How can I do this? Do I need to use a different syntax for optional arguments than in normal use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples:

Backquoted list:

```
ELISP> (let ((foo "Foo")) `(,foo bar))
("Foo" bar)
```

Function `LIST`:

```
ELISP> (let ((foo "Foo")) (list foo 'bar))
("Foo" bar)
```

Example:

```
(setq
 org-publish-project-alist
 `(("my-notes"
    :base-directory ,my-base-directory
    :base-extension "org"
    :publishing-directory ,my-publishing-directory
  ;  ...
    )))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is like ... utterly, completely illegible. What is that supposed to mean? And anyways: I do not want a list, I want to evaluate a single variable. I do not think that `:base-directory` will accept a list.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: You want a list. See in my examples how `foo` is evaluated and `bar` is not. This has nothing to do with `:base-directory`.

Comment: Indeed: `byte-code: Wrong type argument: stringp, (\` ((\, my-base-directory)))`

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: your attempt does not make sense. Construct the whole list, not the argument.

Comment: Well, I *need* to pass the variable's value to the optional parameter `:base-directory`

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: then create a list like I showed you which contains all the necessary elements. The whole list.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I must say that elisp is the only language that I know of that forces me to change the way I call a function just because I want to use a variable instead of a literal. In all languages it is enough to replace the literal by the variable name, and it *just works*.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide: Lisp has a different way how syntax, data structures and code works. The Emacs Lisp manual describes how it works. For example: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html#Backquote

Comment: @jeckyll2hide If you write "[a,b]" in python (inside double-quotes), neither a or b, or the list are evaluated inside the string, they are quoted: you would have to use eval in order to build a list, but this won't happen automatically. The same applies with quote in Lisp: the whole quoted list is left unevaluated.

Comment: @coredump: I guess I still do not understand why I was using `'` in the first place (code was comming from the org-mode manual) ... Maybe because there were references to some variables / function definitions (not shown in my snippet here) which should be left unevaluated.

Answer (score 4):

I see you've already got a working answer, but have expressed some confusion in your comments; I'll try then to explain it more thoroughly.

When you quote something (either by using `(quote foo)` or `'foo`), you are telling the lisp interpreter not to evaluate foo. This is usually used to input data instead of code; in this case you are creating a moderately complicated list structure to be used as data, rather than as code to be evaluated.

Your code had `'(("my-notes" :base-directory my-base-directory))`, which is a quoted list of lists. The inner list will contain the keyword `:base-directory` and the symbol `my-base-directory`. It doesn't contain the value of the my-base-directory variable because the quote at the beginning has told lisp not to evaluate any of it.

The two ways of getting around this both involve not quoting the whole expression.

The first and simplest option is to use `list`; this is a function which takes any number of arguments and returns a list containing those values. For example:

```
(list 1 2 3) => '(1 2 3)
(let ((x 42)) (list x x)) => '(42 42)
```

Thus, you could structure your code like this:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      (list (list "my-notes" :base-directory my-base-directory
                             :base-extension "org"
                             :publishing-directory my-publishing-directory)))
```

You'll see that you have to call the `list` function twice, once for each level of the structure. This can get tedious as the structure becomes more complex; quoting was invented to save you this tedium.

(Note also that keywords and strings evaluate to themselves, so they don't need any special treatment when used as arguments rather than members of quoted lists.)

The other option is to use a backquote (or syntax quote as it is occasionally called) instead of a normal `quote`. The backquote is unusual in that it can be undone using the comma operator:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      `(("my-notes" :base-directory ,my-base-directory
                    :base-extension "org"
                    :publishing-directory ,my-publishing-directory)))
```

The backquote tells lisp not to evaluate the expression, just like the normal quote, but later on the commas let you change your mind and have lisp evaluate some expressions after all.

Backquotes are a bit like Python's string interpolation, except that they apply to the entirety of lisp syntax rather than just to double-quoted strings.

Also, you can put arbitrary lisp expressions after a comma, just like you can put arbitrary lisp expressions after a quote or backquote:

```
`(("my-notes" :base-directory ,(concat my-projects-directory "notes")))
```

Note especially that `(("my-notes" :base-directory, my-base-directory)) won't work; one of your comments indicates that you probably tried something like this. This use of the comma is indeed quite foreign to programmers coming from other languages! You are not alone in thinking that this is a very strange way to write things, but after a while it does start to make sense. It helps to think of the comma as a sort of upside-down backquote.